# Android API level 29 with firemonkey 10.3.3 not working on Android v.10.0 devices

Tags: android, api, delphi, firemonkey

sorry if this question is a duplicate but for my specific issue I couldn't find a solution anywhere.
I followed the post on IDERA community about how to update your app to run in the latest stable API level of Android SDK but it didn't work: `https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/platforms/f/android-platform`

My issue is with devices running android v10.0, my project works fine in all devices from 4.4 to 9.0 and I'm allowed to publish new apps into the appstore when I change the android:targetSdkVersion="29" of AndroidManifest.xml, since last week I had to start posting my apps with the new play console in API level 29.

I use Delphi 10.3.3 CE since 10.4 hasn't released a CE version yet, I have my SDK and NDK all updated to latest version in the SDK Manager. There are no compile errors, it generates the .aab just fine, I can upload to store, it works on all versions from 4.4 to 9.0, but not in 10.0. What should I do?

These are the pictures of how I configured my SDK Manager in the IDE:

```
https://prnt.sc/u9etou
https://prnt.sc/u9eugo
https://prnt.sc/u9euo6
```

Comment: Please refer to the workaround posted by Horacio Filho in the comments in this report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27218

Comment: I did the steps mentioned there but I still can't make it work, I'm trying to setup an emulator but its giving me headaches missing ABIs. Once I can confirm its working will let you know

Comment: Apparently Delphi doesn't like intel emulators so I am not able to make an AVD to test out if that worked or not. The apk that I sent to the store in .aab didn't work, don't know if they're related or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of researching and talking with folks everywhere, I managed to find the solution and I compiled it into a video. The video is in portuguese brazillian as it is my main language but if it helps someone, here's the solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRMPuZxi0fI

All the required files are in the video description but here's the steps that you wanna do:

1. Download the latest SDK 29 files from Android Studio SDK Manager or Embarcadero SDK Manager (In the video I show how to use Android Studio SDK Manager)
2. Replace some precompiled files in your Delphi installation folder, `somethingsomething/Embarcadero/Studio/20.0/` Files in the video description.
3. Configure your SDK inside the Tools > Options > SDK Manager to the latest SDK 29 which is also shown step-by-step in the video.
4. Review your project configurations in Project > Options, make sure you have selected the Generate Android App Bundle option.
5. clean, build, deploy your .aab file, send it to the Play Store and you app now works for Android 10.

Comment: Nice answer, do you change some for android 11 in your sdk path in Rad Studio?

Comment: @user_odoo If you're using Android Studio, update your SDK version up to 30, in RAD Studio, if you followed the video, where I set the API level 29 you change to 30. On your Android.ManifestTemplate you hardcode the %targetSdkVersion% to 30. In the video description there is the template manifest that you can copy with some legacy compatibility like SQLite databases not working.

Comment: Don't understend your last sentences,  In the video description there is the template manifest that you can copy with some legacy compatibility like SQLite databases not working. What not working?

Comment: When add sdk to rad studio I don't have 64-bit version only 32 is that important?

Comment: The legacy compatibility is for when you make your app in newer android versions and it doesn't connect to your database hanging on a black screen forever. You need the Android 64bit to make the .aab in order to publish apps into PlayStore. In the future they plan on removing the 32 bit version altogether because the 64 one can address more memory.

Comment: I'm try create blank fmx app with one button and set in rad studio android-30, change in android manifest to target 30 but when try ap on Android 11 not working.

Comment: @user_odoo how's your manifest targetSdkVersion after you generate the .apk? Also check users permissions, disable everything.

Comment: @Android 10 and 11 working now on Api 29 .apk build with Rad Stduio 10.4